# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Component: ([object Object]?)

Tags: angular6, angular-components, angular-forms

So, before You read the whole error stack, keep in mind that at this time I cant pinpoint the exact piece that causes the problem. However, I will disclose the code below the error stack. So, my only question is: **what parameters can't be resolved?**

If you like, you can test my application for yourself. It is a simple default angular 6 application with all the default settings you get from the following command below:

```
ng new app-name
```

let's begin with the error. The application starts like normal. When I try to run the code, this error pops up:  Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Component: ([object Object]?). You can read the full error stack below.

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Component: ([object Object]?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:1016)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:10917)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:10810)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:10429)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:10291)
    at compiler.js:23865
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at compiler.js:23864
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:23861)
syntaxError @ compiler.js:1016
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata @ compiler.js:10917
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata @ compiler.js:10810
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata @ compiler.js:10429
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata @ compiler.js:10291
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:23865
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:23864
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules @ compiler.js:23861
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:23839
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:23799
push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:143
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4352
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

As you see, there is no easy way of telling which part of my typescript is causing the problem. However, The application runs fine without the code in component.ts shown below. So, there is definitely something wrong with my typescript component.ts

the component.ts is shown below:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, ViewChild, Directive} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { DefineBusinessRuleService } from '../services/define/define-business-rule.service';
import { DefineBusinessRuleNamespace } from '../model/business-rule-namespace';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-define-business-rule',
  templateUrl: './define-business-rule.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./define-business-rule.component.css']
})
export class DefineBusinessRuleComponent implements OnInit {
  // interfaces
  headers : Headers;
  output: any;
  @Input() minValue: string;
  @Input() maxValue: string;
  @Input() attribute : Array<string>;
  @Input() table : Array<string>;

  submitted = false;
  @Input() businessRuleType : Array<string>;
  ruletypes : Array<string>;
  ruletype : string;

  constructor(
    private defineBusinessRuleService: DefineBusinessRuleService
    ,private model : any
  ) {
    this.table = ['table1', 'table2', 'table3'];
    this.attribute = ['attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3'];
    this.ruletypes = [
      // atrribute
      'AttributeRange',
      'AttributeCompare',
      'AttributeList',
      'AttributeOther',
      'TupleCompare',
      'TupleOther'

    ]
    model = {
      minValue : 5,
      maxValue : 10,
      name : 'RangeRule',
      description : 'This is a Range Rule',
      table1 : this.table[0],
      column1 : this.attribute[2],
      errorMsg : 'Error message'
    };
}

  get diagnostic() { return JSON.stringify(this.model); }

  defineNewBusinessRule() {
    //this.model = new DefineBusinessRuleService(42, 50, '', '', '', '', '');

  }

  saveAttributeRangeRule(){
    this.output = {
      database_id : 1,
      minValue : this.minValue,
      maxValue : this.maxValue,
      table1 : this.table,
      column1 : this.attribute
    }
    this.output.stringify;
    this.defineBusinessRuleService.saveAttributeRangeRule(this.output);
  }

  saveAttributeCompareRule(){
    this.output = {
      database_id : 1,
      table1 : this.table,
      //table2 : this.table2,
      column1 : this.attribute,
      //column2 : this.attribute2,
      //value : this.value
    }
    this.output.stringify;
    //this.defineBusinessRuleService.saveAttributeCompareRule(this.output);
  }

  ngOnInit(){

  }

  onSelect(){

  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.ruletype = this.ruletypes[0];
    switch(this.ruletype){
      case "AttributeRange" : {
        this.saveAttributeRangeRule();
        break;
      };
      case "AttributeCompare" : {
        this.saveAttributeCompareRule();
        break;
      };
    }
  }



}
```

Thanks for reading this! If you are visually orientated like me, then this form might help you understand what this code should do. However, it's off topic, since i'm certain enough that it doesn't cause operational problems in angular. keep that in mind!

the related html form is shown below

```html
<br>
<br>

<main role="main" class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Define Business Rule</h1>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #defineBusinessRuleForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="minValue">Minimum Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="minValue">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="maxValue">Maximum Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="maxValue">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name"
               #name="ngModel">
        <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
        class="alert alert-danger">
        Name is required
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="table">Table</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="table" required>
          <option *ngFor="let tbl of table" [value]="table">{{tbl}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="attribute">Attribute</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="attribute" required>
          <option *ngFor="let attr of attribute" [value]="attribute">{{attr}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="errorMsg">Error Message</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="errorMsg" required>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!defineBusinessRuleForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="defineNewBusinessRule(); defineBusinessRuleForm.reset()">Define New BR</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the model definition location.

`private model: any` should be defined as a parameter outside of a constructor.
By placing it in the constructor, the compiler is trying to resolve `any` class, and, naturally is unable to do so.

Modify your code this way:

```js
export class DefineBusinessRuleComponent implements OnInit {
  private model : any

  constructor() {
    this.model = {
      // your model definition
    };
  }

  // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: I have a model definition called businessRuleNamespace Without initializing it. It seems to work. Maybe I'll disclose that class in the near future! thanks for your reply

Comment: I see now that you provided the answer. It works better in my other more recent projects to define it like that. My bad.

Comment: I'm glad if it was helpful